# Setting up ONNX Runtime on Ubuntu 20.04 (C++ API)

Tags: c++, onnx, onnxruntime

I am currently in the midst of trying to get my image processing programs to work on Ubuntu (coming from windows).

I have successfully built and linked the OpenCV and Boost libraries to work with my cpp programs but ***I have yet to find any instructions as to setting up Onnx Runtime C++ on Ubuntu 20.04*** other than using the following command with NuGet Package manager for a specific Visual Studio Project:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime -Version 1.4.0
```

When on Windows, I would only need use the NuGet package manager to download the library for the given visual studio project. It seems possible to do this on Ubuntu using NuGet, but I was wondering if I could do it more "manually" like the boost and OpenCV building and installing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the default CPU version, you can download the tgz file [here](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/releases/tag/v1.4.0).

For other flavors of ONNX runtime that are not available as tgz or NuGet (e.g. TensorRT), you can build them locally:

```
./build.sh --cudnn_home <path to cuDNN e.g. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/> --cuda_home <path to folder for CUDA e.g. /usr/local/cuda> --use_tensorrt --tensorrt_home <path to TensorRT home>
```

More instructions can be found at [Building ONNX Runtime](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/BUILD.md#cuda)

Comment: could you please specify where to find `<path to TensorRT home>` ?

Answer (score 3):

**Installing the NuGet Onnxruntime Release on Linux**

*Tested on Ubuntu 20.04*

For the newer releases of onnxruntime that are available through [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime/) I've adopted the following workflow: Download the release (here 1.7.0 but you can update the link accordingly), and install it into `~/.local/`. For a global (system-wide) installation you may put the files in the corresponding folders under `/usr/local/`.

```sh
mkdir /tmp/onnxInstall
cd /tmp/onnxInstall
wget -O onnx_archive.nupkg https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime/1.7.0
unzip onnx_archive.nupkg
cp runtimes/linux-x64/native/libonnxruntime.so ~/.local/lib/
cp -r build/native/include/ ~/.local/include/onnxruntime/
```

**Cmake**

Now if you want to be able to `find_package(onnxruntime)` from your Cmake package, I suggest you place my self-created onnx cmake files in `~/.local/share/cmake/onnxruntime`. The files are:

`cat ~/.local/share/cmake/onnxruntime/onnxruntimeVersion.cmake`:

```
# Custom cmake version file by jcarius

set(PACKAGE_VERSION "1.7.0")

# Check whether the requested PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION is compatible
if("${PACKAGE_VERSION}" VERSION_LESS "${PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION}")
  set(PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE FALSE)
else()
  set(PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
  if("${PACKAGE_VERSION}" VERSION_EQUAL "${PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION}")
    set(PACKAGE_VERSION_EXACT TRUE)
  endif()
endif()
```

`cat ~/.local/share/cmake/onnxruntime/onnxruntimeConfig.cmake`

```
# Custom cmake config file by jcarius to enable find_package(onnxruntime) without modifying LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
#
# This will define the following variables:
#   onnxruntime_FOUND        -- True if the system has the onnxruntime library
#   onnxruntime_INCLUDE_DIRS -- The include directories for onnxruntime
#   onnxruntime_LIBRARIES    -- Libraries to link against
#   onnxruntime_CXX_FLAGS    -- Additional (required) compiler flags

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

# Assume we are in <install-prefix>/share/cmake/onnxruntime/onnxruntimeConfig.cmake
get_filename_component(CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
get_filename_component(onnxruntime_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../" ABSOLUTE)

set(onnxruntime_INCLUDE_DIRS ${onnxruntime_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)
set(onnxruntime_LIBRARIES onnxruntime)
set(onnxruntime_CXX_FLAGS "") # no flags needed


find_library(onnxruntime_LIBRARY onnxruntime
    PATHS "${onnxruntime_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib"
)

add_library(onnxruntime SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET onnxruntime PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${onnxruntime_LIBRARY}")
set_property(TARGET onnxruntime PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${onnxruntime_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
set_property(TARGET onnxruntime PROPERTY INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "${onnxruntime_CXX_FLAGS}")

find_package_handle_standard_args(onnxruntime DEFAULT_MSG onnxruntime_LIBRARY onnxruntime_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```